# How to declaration username and password of the repositories when submit spark application

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

My private repositories need username and password to visit.
I can't find a way to declaration the username and password when submit

```
bin/spark-submit --repositories   http://wx.bjdv.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/bigdata/ --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi   --master local[8]   examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.1.jar   100
```

The rep http://wx.bjdv.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/bigdata/ need username and password

Comment: try `--repositories http://username:password@wx.bjdv.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/bigdata/`

Comment: really really really helpful